# Process text file with any field delimeter

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I need to process file in spring batch and file delimiter can change. for instance in first file, file field delimiter is comma. And when second file is received that has file field delimiter tab.. How this type of file can be processed in spring batch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define beans for `LineMapper` and `Reader` of Step level scope which will execute for each step.

### LineMapper Bean

```
    @Bean("lineMapper")
    @StepScope
    public LineMapper<YourCustomRecordVo> lineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<YourCustomRecordVo> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<YourCustomRecordVo>();

        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer("yourDelimiter");

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        //set fieldset mappers etc

        return lineMapper;
    }
```

### Reader Bean

```
@Bean(name = "reader")
@StepScope
public YourCustomReader reader(){
    YourCustomReader  reader = new YourCustomReader();
    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
    //set others necessary properties
    return reader;
}
```

Here both `reader` & `lineMapper` beans will be created for each step(i.e for each file processing). So you can set different delimiters depending on different conditions.

### Updated

In order to use your custom delimiter, you can set it as job properties like

```
JobParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
paramsBuilder.addString("delimiter", "yourCustomDelimiter");
```

and lunch job like

```
jobLauncher.run(job, paramsBuilder.toJobParameters());
```

Finally retrieve that job parameters(delimiter in current case) as

```
    @Bean("lineMapper")
    @StepScope
    public LineMapper<YourCustomRecordVo> lineMapper(@Value("#{jobParameters['delimiter']}") String delimiter) {...}
```

Comment: Actually file field delimiter can be different for different text files, and I don't know which file has which delimiter.. Is this achievable in spring batch ?

Comment: @R.Ali no, but you can do something like define your delimiter inside each text file. So first read that delimiter from text file manually(before starting job) and then using that delimiter define your configuration beans

Comment: I can not define delimiter in first row because file has a format but I can follow your direction means I can determine delimiter from file data. Data in first file will be like this:  
a,b,c,d  
and data in second file will be like this:  
a b c d  
so I can get field delimiter by checking if row has comma, semicolon or tab and then I will set this delimiter for spring batch..